# Push django app to IBM Bluemix

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud, push

I am currently trying to push my local Django App to IBM Bluemix servers. I am using Cloud-foundry to do it and the cf command.

Here is the error i get when i'm using the following command:
cf push my-app

```
     $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       test os1913
       55 static files copied to '/tmp/app/backoffice2/static'.
Exit status 0
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (155M)
Uploaded droplet (223.8M)
Uploading complete
Destroying container
Successfully destroyed container

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed
FAILED
Error restarting application: Start unsuccessful
```

I tried to use the cf logs in order to see what's wrong in my push but in vain. You can see below the result of this cf logs.

```
   2017-10-19T08:14:07.05+0000 [STG/0] OUT      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   2017-10-19T08:14:07.46+0000 [STG/0] OUT        test os1913
   2017-10-19T08:14:08.57+0000 [STG/0] OUT        55 static files copied to '/tmp/app/backoffice2/static'.
   2017-10-19T08:16:37.61+0000 [STG/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-10-19T08:16:37.61+0000 [STG/0] OUT Staging complete
   2017-10-19T08:16:37.61+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
   2017-10-19T08:16:37.61+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
   2017-10-19T08:16:37.61+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading droplet...
   2017-10-19T08:16:45.42+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (155M)
   2017-10-19T08:16:54.71+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploaded droplet (223.8M)
   2017-10-19T08:16:54.75+0000 [STG/0] OUT Uploading complete
   2017-10-19T08:16:54.86+0000 [STG/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-10-19T08:16:57.68+0000 [STG/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-10-19T08:17:05.38+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-10-19T08:17:06.47+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-10-19T08:17:23.66+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-10-19T08:17:25.93+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: normal-start-command: No such file or directory
   2017-10-19T08:17:25.93+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2017-10-19T08:17:25.97+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-10-19T08:17:26.00+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-10-19T08:17:26.02+0000 [API/0] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-10-19T08:17:26.03+0000 [API/0] OUT App instance exited with guid d470d027-d5c6-48e5-9883-c4e950e4c7b8 payload: {"instance"=>"93c5bc85-71b6-475b-486d-66e7", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 1\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1508401045980916586, "version"=>"81113fa3-598a-495c-97a8-2032968858cd"}
   2017-10-19T08:17:27.99+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-10-19T08:17:35.12+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-10-19T08:17:36.51+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-10-19T08:17:56.99+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.60+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: normal-start-command: No such file or directory
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.66+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.75+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.78+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.80+0000 [API/1] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-10-19T08:17:59.81+0000 [API/1] OUT App instance exited with guid d470d027-d5c6-48e5-9883-c4e950e4c7b8 payload: {"instance"=>"2c057e8c-0955-43e5-6e97-b61f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 1\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1508401079759915860, "version"=>"81113fa3-598a-495c-97a8-2032968858cd"}
   2017-10-19T08:18:01.75+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2017-10-19T08:18:02.39+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
   2017-10-19T08:18:03.69+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2017-10-19T08:18:29.97+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.30+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR bash: normal-start-command: No such file or directory
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.31+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.49+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.50+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.52+0000 [API/2] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web"
   2017-10-19T08:18:32.53+0000 [API/2] OUT App instance exited with guid d470d027-d5c6-48e5-9883-c4e950e4c7b8 payload: {"instance"=>"cb2d7d3c-6c89-4f4a-762f-054f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 1\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>3, "crash_timestamp"=>1508401112496966489, "version"=>"81113fa3-598a-495c-97a8-2032968858cd"}
   2017-10-19T08:18:34.87+0000 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What is the command you used? How does the manifest.yml look like? Is your Django app CF-ready? How does the code that starts the app look like (look for PORT)? It seems that CF has trouble starting your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 key files which you need to get right. The first is manifest.yml, which sets up the cloud foundry build pack, the second is requirements.txt which defines your app dependencies, the third is runtime.txt which declares the python version.

One of these will not be right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article which showcases Python + Django + Bluemix combination - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-worldbank-charting-app/index.html

You need to have the manifest.yml right.

Do go through the article and hope it helps.